# Сохранение лучшего результата в игре

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Надо сохранить лучший результат. Какие есть варианты сохранения?
*Не использую libgdx.*

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.OnSharedPreferenceChanged("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
best = prefs.getInt("score", 0);

if (best > player.getScore()) {
    canvas.drawText("BEST: " + best, WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
} else {
    best = player.getScore();
    canvas.drawText("BEST: " + best, WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
    prefs.edit().putInt("score", best).apply();
}
```

Решил проблему.
Для меня подошел такой вот код:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("BEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

А вообще, *SharedPreferences* очень даже хитрая штука.
Обязателен какой либо *Context* и учитывайте это! В моём случае - я прописал код при создании новой игры и при окончании. Это тоже учитывайте!

Comment: То как вы выводите результат на экран, никак не связано с тем как вы его будете хранить.

Comment: Файл, база для сингла. Сервер бд с апи для остального.

Comment: как лучше сделать для меньшего использования памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для меня подошел такой вот код:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("BEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

А вообще, *SharedPreferences* очень даже хитрая штука.
Обязателен какой либо *Context* и учитывайте это! В моём случае - я прописал код при создании новой игры и при окончании. Это тоже учитывайте!

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того какая у вас игра. Если это просто синглплей и данный юзер и его счет не связан с другими игроками то вам вполне хватит SharedPreferences. Если игра более сложная то уточните детали.

Comment: Использую вот такой вот код, но OnSharedPreferenceChanged выделяет красным. Игра простая, только конкретный пользователь может знать свой рекорд.