# Сохранение прогресса в приложении

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как сделать так чтобы прогресс(int) сохранялся и был доступен для следующего использования? Мне нужно чтоб данные кэшировались

Comment: Способов так много, что они просто не поместятся в ответ. Вам придётся как-то уточнить вопрос. Следующее использование - это на другом девайсе через N времени после запроса актуальных данных? Если так - то нужен бекэнд, авторизация, БД и прочая. Примерно неделя работы профессионала.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мне нужно чтобы без авторизации

Comment: авторизация это вообще о другом. Юрий говорит о способе хранения данных. можно хранить в оперативной памяти, в кэше, в файлике да телефоне, в базе данных, в облаке, где угодно

Comment: SharedPrefs юзай

Comment: @SviatVolkov без авторизации, значит не в бд и облаке.

Comment: @Alex78191 для SQLite не требуется авторизация, но для хранения одного значения использовать БД несколько чрезмерно. Для этих целей, как вы и сказали наиболее правильно [использовать `SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Дубликат • https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568304/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5 • https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632456/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-checkbox?rq=1

Comment: @Alex78191 Те вопросы, что вы указали отличаються от моего.

Comment: @MixBab суть одна

Comment: @MixBab Что именно вам не ясно по решению вашей проблемы по предложенным уже имеющимся ответам?

Comment: @pavlofff В этих вопросах толком не сказанно как это сделать. Мне нужно чтобы 4 int сохранялись и снова использовались по нажатию кнопки. Так как их сохранить?